# Preventing to Close the First Form by Closing the Other

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

Good Morning.

I have a Program that has a 3 Forms and they are.

```
MainMenu
Form1
Form2
```

I have a `MenuStrip` in `MainMenu` and when I click it `Form1` will show and the code for that is the Simple `Form1.show` now I have some procedures that has a Connect with `Form2` Lets say I opened `Form2` using `Form1` so the `Form1` is still open and `Form2` is on the Top of it and when Im done in `Form2` I will close it using `Button` named Close.

But my concern here is when I close it the `Form1` automatically Hides and I dont want that to happen.

Here is my Code in `Button` Close

```
'Do some MySQL Command
Me.close
```

My Question here is that How can I prevent the first Form from Hiding when the Second Form closes. Usually it happens when theres a changes in the Second Form.

I hope someone helps me with this one. TYSM for future help.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There's nothing about closing one form that will inherently make another form hide.  Presumably the button is on the `MainMenu` form so clicking it will give that form focus.  That's how it should work.  If you want to give another form focus then you need to call its `Activate` method.

Comment: Please see the Edited Post

Comment: For Example I have 2 Forms Form2 on the top of Form1 when Form2 closes the Form1 Minimizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you did not mentioned any code that navigate forms.

As per your information provided, I have put some code that may help you.

```
Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Form1.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Put above mentioned code in Form2 code.

If you want to stop minimizing Form1 on Form2 close then you can use following code.

```
Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Form1.WindowState=FormWindowState.Maximized     
    Form1.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

Comment: `BringToFront` is for affecting the z-order of child controls.  If what you actually want is a top-level form to have focus then you call its `Activate` method.

Comment: Please see the Edited Post

Comment: For Example I have 2 Forms Form2 on the top of Form1 when Form2 closes the Form1 Minimizes

Comment: For stop Form1 to Minimizes I have updated my answer